# Map Interface in Java

Tags: java, reference

Does the `Map#get` method return the value that the key is mapped to or does it return a reference to the value? 
Code(This is a program I am working on):

```
    Map<String,Vector<String>> map=new TreeMap<String,Vector<String> >();  
    for(String line:services)
    {
         String[] set=line.split(" ");
         Vector<String> t=new Vector<String>();
         String BioService=set[0];             
         int i=1;              
         while(i<set.length)
         {  
              t.clear();                        
              if(map.containsKey(set[i]))
                  t=map.get(set[i]);                                                                                          
              t.addElement(BioService);               
              map.put(set[i],t);
              /*if i put t.clear() here i get null values in my output*/                                                                                                                                     
              i++;                
         }       
     }
```

Comment: on a side note, you should consider using `ArrayList` instead of `Vector` if you are not managing multiple threads

Comment: I am only a beginner so i don't much about managing threads. My problem is how can i avoid affecting the values of the vector t. Suppose i put t.clear() after map.put(set[i],t); the corresponding entry in the map also has a empty value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It returns a reference to the Object.

You will never have the actual Object in Java, only ever a reference to it.

You do have actual primitives (and cannot have references to primitives, only references to Objects that wrap primitives or something like that), but of course primitives cannot be put into maps, only Objects can.

Let's say you have the following code:

```
Map<String,Vector<String>> map = new HashMap... // etc
Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>();
vec.addElement("foo");
map.put("foo",vec);
vec.clear();
vec.addElement("bar");
map.put("bar",vec);

Vector<String> ret = map.get("foo");
System.out.println(ret.get(0)); // prints bar
```

You only ever use one single vector. You put your vector into the map, and then on the next iteration you clear it. Well, you just cleared the vector that's inside the map! Just because you put it in the map doesn't mean it can't be changed.

Your best bet, I feel, would be to make a new vector for each entry.

So replace

```
t.clear();
```

with

```
t = new Vector<String>();
```

Comment: Could you explain why if i put t.clear() after using put method i get null values in the map?

Comment: There aren't null values in the map - there are NO values in the map. Since every key you enter will have no value associated with it, null is returned. From the Javadoc for `get(K)`, "Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key."

Comment: What i mean to say is how does changing the position of t.clear() affect the values of the key? Since i am new to Java, I find some difficulty in understanding this.

Comment: Well by looking at your code, you are using a `Map<String,Vector>`, but you only ever use the exact same vector. I'll edit a better response into my answer.

Comment: I checked the Oracle Documentation for Java but couldn't find that it returns a reference. What exactly are non-primitive data types?

Comment: If it extends `Object` it is non-primitive. So anything that is not `int short char double float long byte boolean`.

Comment: Another thing that is confusing me is that since t is a reference to the vector in map,regardless of wherever i put t.clear() it should clear the referred vector in map also but this is not the case since the output is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

All non primitive types are handled as references in Java. Hence, the `get` method will return a reference to the mapped item.